# Rewrite stateful code to be more DRY

Tags: ruby, coding-style, dry, code-cleanup

I have this block of code wherein every next set of lines depends on the previous response and the set of steps must follow a fixed path making it slightly stateful.

This is causing my method to grow in size and a lot of code repetition (even though the variables and data are different). How can I DRY-up this code?

```
def process
  response = ServiceResponse.new(false, [])

  # Step 1
  project_path = import_project()

  if project_path.present?
    response.data << Step.new('import', true, "Project imported")
    send_realtime_data(response)

    hr_config, hr_config_error = fetch_hr_config(project_path)
    weighted_scores_config, ws_error = fetch_weighted_scores(project_path)

    if hr_config.blank?
      response.data << Step.new('.hr_config.yml', false, hr_config_error || "Empty configuration file")
      return response
    else
      response.data << Step.new('.hr_config.yml', true, 'Configuration file found')
      send_realtime_data(response)
    end

    if weighted_scores_config.blank? && ws_error.present?
      response.data << Step.new('.hr_weighted_scores.yml', false, ws_error)
      return response
    else
      response.data << Step.new('.hr_weighted_scores.yml', true, "Weighted scoring config found")
      send_realtime_data(response)
    end

    configuration = ::X::FullStack::Configuration.new(
      hr_config, {weighted_scores: weighted_scores_config}
    )

    if !configuration.valid?
      response.data << Step.new('validate_configuration', false, "Configuration validation failed", configuration.validations.as_json)
      return response
    else
      response.data << Step.new('validate_configuration', false, "Configuration validated successfully", configuration.validations.as_json)
      send_realtime_data(response)
    end

    #....

  end
end
```

The response to this method is shared via a websocket (code is from a rails delayed task), `send_realtime_data` method sends data to the frontend. When the method concludes (via `return`), the task completes and the return value is sent to the frontend followed by closing of the websocket.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` branches are redundant.

```
def process
  response = ServiceResponse.new(false, [])
  project_path = import_project
  if project_path.blank?
    return
  end

  response.data << Step.new('import', true, "Project imported")
  send_realtime_data(response)    
  hr_config, hr_config_error = fetch_hr_config(project_path)
  weighted_scores_config, ws_error = fetch_weighted_scores(project_path)
  if hr_config.blank?
    response.data << Step.new('.hr_config.yml', false, hr_config_error || "Empty configuration file")
    return response
  end

  response.data << Step.new('.hr_config.yml', true, 'Configuration file found')
  send_realtime_data(response)
  if weighted_scores_config.blank? && ws_error.present?
    response.data << Step.new('.hr_weighted_scores.yml', false, ws_error)
    return response
  end

  response.data << Step.new('.hr_weighted_scores.yml', true, "Weighted scoring config found")
  send_realtime_data(response)
  configuration = ::X::FullStack::Configuration.new(
    hr_config, {weighted_scores: weighted_scores_config}
  )
  unless configuration.valid?
    response.data << Step.new('validate_configuration', false, "Configuration validation failed", configuration.validations.as_json)
    return response
  end

  response.data << Step.new('validate_configuration', false, "Configuration validated successfully", configuration.validations.as_json)
  send_realtime_data(response)

  #....
end
```